# best way to use Lock instance in a POJO class

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a Sample Banking application. to make banking operations (deposit, withdraw, transfer etc) thread safe i want to use Lock interface. I need to lock the Account instance for the banking operation happening on that particular account. 
For example in deposit(Account account, Double amountToDeposit) i want to lock the account instance so multiple deposit operations can happen simultaneously  on different accounts.

Can i have a Lock instance in Account pojo, is it a good coding practice as per design guidelines ?
what is the best way to achieve this functionality?

```
public class Account{
   private final Long accountNumber;
   private Double balance;
   private final Lock lock;

  // constructor, getters and setter 
}
```

below is sample code for the banking transaction-

```
public class Transaction{
   public void deposit(Account accunt, Double amount){
     account.getLock().lock();
     //validation and transaction logic
     account.getLock().unLock();
  }
}
```

Comment: *i want to lock the account instance so multiple deposit operations can happen simultaneously on different accounts* doesn't make sense to me. Do you want to allow or disallow simultanious access to an account instance?

Comment: i want disallow simultaneous access to that particular account instance, but in another thread another deposit can happening on different account, that should not be blocked. that's why i want to Lock the Account instance not the deposit functionality.

Comment: Then it should work, yes

Comment: its working fine, my question being- is it a good practice to have the Lock instance in POJO class as per  design guidelines ? is there any other way to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: a simpler solution would probably be to use `synchronized(account){ /* logic */ }` instead of introducing that lock

Comment: yes, synchronized(account) is one way, but i want use Locking API specifically.

Comment: You may also consider locking only for write/modify operations, and leave read-only operations unlocked.